# Re-ordering and appending an additional column to .SD output

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to apply a scalar function (like `mean`) to a primary group, and rank the values within a secondary group. This is a sample code for what I am trying to do:

```
library(data.table)
mytestdata <- data.table(name=c("tom","john","tom","john","jim","jim","jack"),
                         len=c(10,15,12,23,3,12,3),
                         group=c("a","b","a","a","a","b","b"))
mytestdata[, .SD[, .(mean(len), .N), by="name"][order(V1)], by = "group"]  # I need the .N to log
```

The output here is as I intend. However, when I try to rank the names within each group, I'm unable to get the desired output.

```
mytestdata[, .SD[, .(mean(len), .N), by="name"][order(V1), myrank := seq(1:.N)], by = "group"]
```

The above code assigns the rank correctly but re-orders the columns to the default ordering (ignoring `order(V1)`, which had worked in the previous line). I assume this has something to do with `:=` not displaying output. Is there a way to fix this?

I tried something like

```
mytestdata[, .(.SD[, .(mean(len), .N), by="name"][order(V1)], seq(1:.N), by = "group"]
```

but it throws an error about bad usage of the `list()` method in `j`.

**EDIT:** My desired output is (ranking should be within group) **(A)**

```
   group name V1 N myrank
1:     a  jim  3 1    1
2:     a  tom 11 2    2
3:     a john 23 1    3
4:     b jack  3 1    1
5:     b  jim 12 1    2
6:     b john 15 1    3
```

**EDIT:** To clarify my point, my original code,

```
mytestdata[, .SD[, .(mean(len), .N), by="name"][order(V1)], by = "group"]
```

returns the datatable sorted in the way I'd like, i.e., **(1)**

```
   group name V1 N
1:     a  jim  3 1
2:     a  tom 11 2
3:     a john 23 1
4:     b jack  3 1
5:     b  jim 12 1
6:     b john 15 1
```

Now, I'd like to keep this ordering and assign ranks to the names within each group. Since `i` is evaluated before `j` in a data.table, I can assign the rank in the same statement as `order()` above, i.e.,

```
mytestdata[, .SD[, .(mean(len), .N), by="name"][order(V1), myrank := 1:.N], by = "group"]
```

This assigns the rank correctly, i.e., **(2)**

```
   group name V1 N myrank
1:     a  tom 11 2      2
2:     a john 23 1      3
3:     a  jim  3 1      1
4:     b john 15 1      3
5:     b  jim 12 1      2
6:     b jack  3 1      1
```

However, the ordering of rows is no longer the same as in **(1)** due to, my guess, the assignment operator suppressing output and storing the data table in the unordered format. Now, to get the output in the form of **(A)**, I have to re-order the rows by grouping again **or** assign the rank column in a chaining method, i.e.,

```
mytestdata[, .SD[, .(mean(len), .N), by="name"][order(V1), myrank := 1:.N], by = "group"][order(rank), .SD, by = "group"]
```

**(OR)**

```
mytestdata[, .SD[, .(mean(len), .N), by="name"][order(V1)], by = "group"][, myrank := 1:.N, by = "group"]
```

This gives the desired output **(A)**. While both these solve my problem, I'm curious whether there is a solution that does away with the additional chaining, since the ranks are assigned correctly in **(2)**, and the order is already correct in **(1)**.

Comment: I think you're just putting it in the wrong place - do you just want `mytestdata[, .SD[, .(mean(len), .N), by=name][order(V1)], by=group][, rank := 1:.N, by=group][]` ?

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks! Is there a way to eliminate the additional grouping just to rank? Specifically, I'm curious why `order(V1)` works in the first case, but does not seem to display the re-ordered rows in the second case, instead assigning the rank after re-ordering but displaying them in the original order.

Comment: Hmmmm.... I'm not seeing how it can be avoided yet. Let me have a think

Comment: `mytestdata[, .(mean_len = mean(len), .N, group, len), by="name"][i  = order(mean_len), j  = .( name, len, mean_len, rank = 1:.N), by = c("group")]
`

Comment: The problem with the above code is that it will not take care of ties in names

Comment: @Sathish your code outputs all rows, which in the test dataset does not look too bad (7 vs 6), but in my real dataset, it's like (1M vs 1K). The data is in long format and many such ties exist.

Comment: If you want to assign mean rank to ties in name, then you may try this `mytestdata[, .(mean_len = mean(len), group, len), by="name"][i  = order(mean_len), j  = .( name, len, mean_len, rank = 1:.N), by = c("group")][, .(rank = mean(rank), len), by = c('group', 'name')]
`

Comment: do you want to add rank column to the existing data?

Comment: No, just a one-off analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are running into problems with the order of processing the i and j arguments to `[.data.table`;

This is what I think you do want, although you only actually provide details of what you don't want:

```
mytestdata[, .SD[, .(mean(len), .N), by="name"]][order(V1),][,rank := rank(V1)][]
   name   V1 N rank
1: jack  3.0 1    1
2:  jim  7.5 2    2
3:  tom 11.0 2    3
4: john 19.0 2    4
```

When the issue of ties came up, I searched on:

```
> ?rank   # Turns out there is a data.table function for that as well, `frank`

> mytestdata[, .SD[, .(mean(len), .N), by="name"]][order(V1),][,rank := frank(V1)][]
   name   V1 N rank
1: jack  3.0 1    1
2:  jim  7.5 2    2
3:  tom 11.0 2    3
4: john 19.0 2    4
```

The separate application of ordering (first)  and calculation of ranks (later) appeared to be what was needed. And if you wanted a different method of calculating ranks, the frank function has: `ties.method=c("average", "first", "random", "max", "min", "dense")`,  The use of a terminal `[]` is something I just learned from @thelatemail. A final comment. I would make the column names more "particular". Using the name of a column like "rank" confuses the user who is accustomed to seeing that as a function name. Better to make it "myrank" or "testrank".

Responding to comment below: I'm still having difficutly understanding exactly what is wanted (specificically what is meant by not wanting "extra grouping at the end") but if the desire is to reorder based on the "new" ranking then why not:

```
 mytestdata[, .SD[, .(mean(len), .N), by=name][order(V1)], by=group][ #
                       , myrank := frank(V1), by=group][order(myrank), ]
   group name V1 N myrank
1:     a  jim  3 1      1
2:     b jack  3 1      1
3:     a  tom 11 2      2
4:     b  jim 12 1      2
5:     a john 23 1      3
6:     b john 15 1      3
```

Comment: Isn't `mytestdata[, .SD[, .(mean(len), .N), by="name"]]` the same as `mytestdata[, .(mean(len), .N), by="name"]`?

Comment: @42- Thanks for your answer! I updated my question with the expected answer. I am actually interested in the `myrank` within the `group`, so a `name` can appear multiple times in the answer, if it occurs in multiple groups.

Comment: The answer by @thelatemail is what I am looking for, but I'm curious whether there is a way to avoid the extra grouping at the end. I realize that ordering in `i` is computed first, and then the `myrank` is assigned in `j` next by `group`, and I am looking for a way to display that ordered output along with the assignment itself, as that is what I need (ordered by rank). Without the assignment, the code works as expected with the correct ordering. But when the assignment happens, the ordering is not "displayed" and just "stored", if that makes sense. I'm trying to work around this.

Comment: @42- please see my second edit where i describe my issue in detail.